# Is it safe to use this code with WordPress to get cloudflare SSL working

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cloudflare

I want to ask if this code snippet is safe to use in WordPress. As I am new and their are many experts here. So I would like to ask them about this code.

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' === $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) { $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; }
```

**This code solves the redirect loop when using cloudflare SSL certificate**.

Many forums and threads I have suggested to use similar code but some say that `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';`  using this code is not a good practice. I want someone to guide

Answer (score 0):

With Cloudflare SSL, there are a [few different options](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes) you can set on how it connects to your Origin server. One option is to have HTTPS only between Cloudflare and your user, an then plaintext / non-HTTPS between Cloudflare and your Origin. This sounds like the option you are using?

The issue with a redirect loop happens when your Origin server tries to redirect (what it correctly views) as non-HTTPS request to HTTPS. However, your user is already on the HTTPS URL. Your Origin server doesn't have visibility of this except through the 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO' header.

By using the code snippet you pasted, it is essentially hiding the fact that the Cloudflare -> Origin connection is only HTTP, and using the fact that the User -> Cloudflare connection is HTTPS instead. This is only half the equation.

The reason the fix can be considered a bad practice is because what you are really doing is masking a problem that could be solved (allowing HTTPS between Cloudflare -> Origin).

Comment: Can you please tell how to enable https between cloudflare and origin and I am using cloudflare argo tunnel

Comment: As long as you are pointing at port 443 (HTTPS) of your Origin server w/ Argo, it should be HTTPS.

Comment: my nginx server doesn't respond and gives 404 error on port 443. Also when connecting through domain it works fine

Comment: I would say that is the root issue here then. If your service isn't responding properly over 443, that means HTTPS won't be accessible. So if you are using the service on port 80 only, that would explain why the connection from Cloudflare -> Origin is plaintext / HTTP.

I think this goes beyond the scope of this questions however.